# If statement returning #NAME error

Tags: excel, if-statement

Basically I have two different columns; column G and H

I would like to make it so that if the Column H is greater than today's date Coloumn G equals "G" for good and if Column H is less than today's date Column G will equal "R" for not on track

```
=IF(H84<TODAY,"R","G")
```

My return is #NAME?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the (). Change:

```
=IF(H84<TODAY,"R","G")
```

To

```
=IF(H84<TODAY(),"R","G")
```

Comment: No problem. Have the same issues sometimes :). Please select my post as answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you check that the date in column F is of date type?
- In my excel the today function has parenthesis, TODAY()